# I want to increase the size of selected tab and indicator also

Tags: android, tabs, tabview

I want to increase the  size of the selected tab with indicator's size. I have three tabs on `TabLayout`:

- The selected tab covers 50% of the area of tab layout.
- The other two tabs each have half of the remaining 50%.

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. Not yet. @V.March